# How to use an isNull expression in an OR condition

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, expression

Cakephp Version: 4.3.5

I'm trying to construct an Or condition that uses an isNull expression in a custom finder.

In text I am trying to do this:

```
public function findMyTasks(Query $query, array $options): object
{
   $query
      ->where([
         'Tasks.status' => $options['status'],
         'Tasks.user_id' => $options['user_id'],
         'OR' => [
             ['Tasks.contact_id' => null], // HERE IS THE CONDITION
             ['Contacts.status' => 1]
         ],
      ]);

    return $query;

 }
```

If I wanted to use isNull in a condition without OR I would use the following:

```
->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
   return $exp->isNull('Tasks.contact_id');
})
```

I have tried various combinations by referencing the advanced condition page [here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions) but I cannot combine the expression with the condition without a syntax error.

**Question:**

How can I construct this finder that uses isNull with an OR condition.

Thanks,
Zenzs.

Comment: Did you try something like this

```
'OR' => [
             ['Tasks.contact_id IS NULL'], // HERE IS THE CONDITION
             ['Contacts.status' => 1]
         ],
```

Comment: I didn't try that and yes is does work so thanks. But I really wanted to know if I can use an expression and isNull in the condition.

Comment: There is no need to use expressions with such simple array key value pairs.

Comment: @mark Thanks for the info about the use of expessions and confirming the isNull function cannot be used. But I am wondering why the is null check above in the expression is more complicated than an is null check as an array key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented:

```
'OR' => [
    ['Tasks.contact_id IS' => null],
    ['Contacts.status' => 1]
],
```

Just a bit further down on that page:
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatic-is-null-creation